# Porque não consigo agrupar dados nessa query?

Tags: sql, firebird, tsql

```
SELECT e.idproduto codigo,
       p.descricaoproduto nome,
       sum(e.qtde) entrada,
       sum(s.qtde) saida
FROM itementrada e
INNER JOIN produto p ON e.idproduto = p.idproduto
INNER JOIN itemsaida s ON p.idproduto = s.idproduto
GROUP BY e.idproduto

can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)
```

Comment: GROUP BY e.idproduto,p.descricaoproduto , creio

Comment: Foi exatamente isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O campo `descricaoproduto` não permite que o agrupamento ocorra. Ou insira ele no `group by`, ou retire o campo de seu `select`.